# How can I play large videos ( > 100MB) from Google Drive into HTML <video> element?

Tags: javascript, html, file, video, google-drive-api

I am working on a project that needs to play videos from Google Drive, and videos can be large in size, movies for example.
I cannot use `<iframe>` for my project since I have different features. I need a solution to play large video files from Google drives into HTML `<video>` element.

I have tried to overcome this by using

```
<video src = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=[FILE ID]"></video>
```

This method works only for small videos that are smaller than 100MB. Videos that are larger don't work as Google redirects to an annoying page that says, "file too big to scan for virus, please confirm download".

To overcome this I tried with Google API key.

```
<video src = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[FILE ID]?alt=media&key=[API KEY]"></video>
```

When the video size is larger than 100MB, this returns the file with the file_id as a name without any file extension; thus, `<video>` element cannot play it.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: A video tag simply does a **GET** request, maybe use JS code to do the GET part yourself? Example: `myFile = fetch("https://www.googleapis.com...etc..etc..");` then update the returned String as `myURL = myFile + ".mp4";` then set `video.src = myURL; video.load(); video.play();` ... The point is to get the text of the file path and update with an extension, before loading it into your video tag through JS code.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Google Drive API:

Go to the Google Cloud Console.
Create a new project (or select an existing one).
Enable the "Google Drive API" for your project.
Create API credentials (OAuth client ID) and download the credentials as a JSON file.
Share the Video File on Google Drive:

Upload your video file to Google Drive.
Right-click on the video file and select "Share."
Make sure the visibility is set to "Anyone with the link" and set the permissions to "Viewer."
Copy the shareable link.
Modify the Shareable Link:

Replace the open part of the link with uc.
Replace https://drive.google.com/file/d/FILE_ID/view?usp=sharing with https://drive.google.com/uc?id=FILE_ID.
For example, if the original link is:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/abcdefgh1234567890/view?usp=sharing
Modify it to:
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=abcdefgh1234567890
Embed the Video in HTML:

Use the modified link as the src attribute for the  tag.

Your browser does not support the video tag.

Make sure to replace https://drive.google.com/uc?id=abcdefgh1234567890 with your modified link.

Comment: This method doesn't play the video. If I paste the URL in browser, it takes me to the "Cannot scan virus,  confirm download" page,

Comment: @PriyanshuChandra Please note: [Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/2057709)